# Dragging a UICollectionViewCell on another element

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, cliptobounds

I want to drag a UICollectionViewCell on another UIView or another element.
I've created a subclass of UICollectionViewCell.

This is my cell class, subclass of UICollectionViewCell:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.dragObject=self;
    self.homePosition = CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                                        self.frame.origin.y);
    [self.superview.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    CGRect newDragObjectFrame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - touchOffset.x,
                                           touchPoint.y - touchOffset.y,
                                           self.frame.size.width,
                                           self.frame.size.height);
    self.frame = newDragObjectFrame;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


            CGRect newFrame =  CGRectMake(self.homePosition.x, self.homePosition.y,
                                          self.frame.size.width,
                                          self.frame.size.height);


            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                             animations:^{
                                 self.frame = newFrame;
                             }];

}
```

[image]

I can drag and drop any UICollectionViewCell in UICollectionView. But I can't drag a cell on another element on the screen. For example another UICollectionView or UIView.

If I set clipToBounds property to "false" then I can drag a cell on anywhere but it doesn't hide overflow content, like scrolled cells.

in this picture, **clipToBounds=false:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if is is possible or not but why you don't just put a UIView over UICollectionViewCell and drag this UIView?
When user tries to drag a cell, just hide the cell and add a UIView that acts like the cell.